# MySQL - Fetch millions of data in chunk with constantly changing data

Tags: java, mysql, database, backend

Below is the schema of my table A.

```
CREATE TABLE A (
      NAME VARCHAR(255),
      CREATED_AT DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      UPDATED_AT DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY(NAME)
);
CREATE INDEX I1 ON A (UPDATED_AT,CREATED_AT);
```

Now we have around 50M records in this table. I can't fetch all the data at once as it would cause memory issues in the backend.
I was thinking to use OFFSET+LIMIT combination to fetch the data in chunks but the problem is that the data is updating after every 5 minutes which can alter the position of the record in the table as we have the index on UPDATED_AT.

We can't afford to read the record twice.
Is there any other way to read a large amount of data in chunks with frequent data updates.

Comment: Not an issue - that’s what transactions are for.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_isolation_level

Comment: Still not clear to me

Comment: When using repeatable-read isolation level, subsequent reads in a given transaction are guaranteed to view data in the same state, as though a snapshot had been taken  of the database. This does not block concurrent updates to the data, but queries in that repeatable-read transaction will not see any updates to the data until the transaction finishes.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. 
So it means that the repeatable read does not take locks on the rows..right? It just maintains a snapshot for query